# How to correctly calculate values from objects?

Tags: javascript

Guys, tell me, please, how to correctly calculate the values from the objects. I have an array:

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        productName: 'Телефон',
        price: 50000,
        count: 2
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        productName: "Телевизор",
        price: 60000,
        count: 3
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        productName: "Компьютер",
        price: 40000,
        count: 5
    }
];
```

where price is the sum of the goods, and count is the amount of the goods added.
How can I calculate the total amount of all added goods?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: The expected output should be 480000. `2x50000 + 3x60000 + 5x40000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()`

```js
const data = [ { id: 1, productName: 'Телефон', price: 50000, count: 2 }, { id: 2, productName: "Телевизор", price: 60000, count: 3 }, { id: 3, productName: "Компьютер", price: 40000, count: 5 } ];

let sum = data.reduce((ac,{count,price}) => ac + price * count, 0);
console.log(sum)
```